# Where to find data sources for music recomendation engine?

Tags: graph-databases, opendata

For my high-school thesis, I'd like to create a recommendation engine. I would like to use a graphdatabase for this task.

I've read some blog posts on this topic, but I got stuck at the first step. Finding good source of data. I've found Spotify Million Playlist Dataset, but Id like to use some more recent data. Does the data source for this exist? Tidal, YouTube, Spotify, Apple, Deezer are my top candidates.

I've asked the same question in [Music Fan beta](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/12881/where-to-find-data-sources-for-music-recomendation-engine) without any luck.

Is the [Spotify Million Playlist Dataset](https://www.aicrowd.com/challenges/spotify-million-playlist-dataset-challenge) the only dataset that I can use?

Comment: I wish you luck with your thesis. That sounds like a fun project. Unfortunately questions looking for suggestions or recommendations tend to get closed by moderators as they require subjective answers. I believe LastFM make part of their API available for free but I have not looked lately. You might also want to take a look at WikiData.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at LastFM. I didn't know about it.